# Help LWC new modal and lightning record form

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightning-experience, help

I have put a LWC lightning record edit page in my modal however I cannot get it to create the record when the button is in the footer of the modal. If btn is the lighting record edit form and not the footer it will create. However for a client I am wanting it to be in the footer not the record edit form itself. I am passing in the lightning record form into the modal by having it placed in the body as

````
     <lightning-card  title={headerText} icon-name="standard: account"> 
         <lightning-modal-header label="Business"></lightning-modal-header> 
         <lightning-modal-body> 
             
             <c-business-entity-form></c-business-entity-form> 

         </lightning-modal-body> 
         <lightning-modal-footer> 
             <lightning-button variant='brand' label={saveBtn} title='title' onclick={handleSave}> 
             </lightning-button> 
             <lightning-button variant='brand' label={saveAndProceedBtn} class="slds-m-left_small" title='title' onclick={handleSave}> 
             </lightning-button> 
         </lightning-modal-footer> 
     </lightning-card> 
 </template>```

In my modal js file how can I save what is in my record edit form

<c-business-entity-form></c-business-entity-form>

being passed in to this modal? I feel like I am just having a brain fart. Any help greatly appreciated.
````

Comment: can you please share the js code also

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of if, your record form seems to be inside `c-business-entity-form` which is a different LWC component and your buttons are on parent LWC component, thus it needs a way to fetch data from your child component `c-business-entity-form`or trigger an submit event inside your child.

here is a solution to do this via `@api` method in your child LWC component. You can trigger a submit event inside your child form from parent form.

For eg:

Child LWC holds your `lightning-record-edit-form`

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Contact" onsubmit={handleCustomSubmit}>
        <lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Name"> </lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button
                class="slds-m-top_small createnew slds-hide"
                type="submit"
                label="Create new"
        >
        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
</template>
```

---

JS for this is :

```
import {api, LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class FormTestBusiness extends LightningElement {

    handleCustomSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();       // stop the form from submitting
        const fields = event.detail.fields;
        console.log('fields -> '+JSON.stringify(fields));
        this.template.querySelector('lightning-record-edit-form').submit(fields);
    }

    @api triggerSubmit(){
        console.log(this.template.querySelector('.createnew'));
        this.template.querySelector('.createnew').click();
    }
}
```

Here I am exposing my `triggerSubmit` button to parent and the submit button on the form itself is hidden from dom using `slds-hide`.

Now from parent:

```
<template>
    <lightning-card  title={headerText} icon-name="standard: account">
        <lightning-modal-header label="Business"></lightning-modal-header>
        <lightning-modal-body>
            <c-form-test-business></c-form-test-business>
        </lightning-modal-body>
        <lightning-modal-footer>
            <lightning-button variant='brand' label="Save Button" title='title' onclick={handleSaveCustom}>
            </lightning-button>
        </lightning-modal-footer>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

I just need to query the child element and trigger my exposed method.

```
import {LightningElement} from 'lwc';

export default class FormTest extends LightningElement {

    handleSaveCustom(event){
        this.template.querySelector('c-form-test-business').triggerSubmit();
    }
}
```

This will internally trigger a `click` event on the form, and hence submitting the form.

[image]

From Console log:

[image]

You can further extend this and write your logic accordingly.

Comment: Also what is lightning messages for does it let the communication happen between components? Thanks again 

Comment: In the above case `<lightning-messages> </lightning-messages>` displays any error which the component receives while saving the record.